# Mapping a function to an image collection, then displaying specific images from new collection Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, function

I'm trying to extract fires from a collection of Landsat images. I have this function that can process a single image, but when I try to use the Map function to map it onto a collection it doesn't seem to work. I think I'm also limited in my understanding of what the function is actually doing when I get the map function to work. After passing the collection through the function, is the collection just a new set of altered images? Or are the altered images stored somewhere else?

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 100))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 49));

var point = ee.Geometry.Point([145.74720448921903,15.185623803783308]);

var image = ee.Image(
  l8.filterBounds(point)
    .filterDate('2019-05-01', '2019-05-30')
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .first()
    );

var fullfunction = function(image){
  var nir = image.select('B5');
  var red = image.select('B7');
  var burnindex = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red));
  
  var saipan = burnindex.clip(boundary);
  var impervious2 = impervious.multiply(500);
  var saipan1 = saipan.subtract(impervious2);
   
  var mask2 = saipan1.gte(-1).and(saipan1.lt(0.15));
  var secondmask = saipan1.updateMask(mask2);
  
  return secondmask;
  
};

var finalimage = fullfunction(image);

Map.addLayer(finalimage,{},'asdf');
//this works

collection.map(fullfunction);
//this doesn't
```

Comment: Can you please paste the complete code? It seems you are using an image called "impervious" which is not defined in the code chunk above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot extract fires with this index (NBR = Normalized Burn Ratio) because you need the difference between NBRs before (NBRb) and after (NBRa) fire (dNBR = NBRb - NBRa). On the other hand, your code in question does not include some definitions. However, it is possible to find out why the function does not work adequately.

With your original function, after passing the collection through it, you would got a new  collection as a new set of altered images. However, in your case, it doesn't work because there is not any assignation (you need something as this: `new_collection = collection.map(fullfunction);`). So, I modified your function for calculating index as **saipan** variable, renamed its band as 'NBR' and, added it to original collection. I also created an arbitrary area around your point and named it as the missing boundary geometry in your code. It [looks now](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9ef13bc7a75c6e20a0b0b556f2b5776d) as follows.

```
var boundary = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[145.73616495432188, 15.172178917548942],
          [145.7562493354254, 15.172344595379078],
          [145.77135553659727, 15.179468619158815],
          [145.7559060126715, 15.194212928077368],
          [145.73770990671446, 15.193384623424764],
          [145.73153009714414, 15.186592402625152]]]);

var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 100))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 49));

var point = ee.Geometry.Point([145.74720448921903,15.185623803783308]);

Map.addLayer(boundary, {'color': 'blue'});
Map.centerObject(boundary);

var image = ee.Image(
  l8.filterBounds(point)
    .filterDate('2019-05-01', '2019-05-30')
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .first()
    );

var fullfunction = function(image){

  var nir = image.select('B5');
  var red = image.select('B7');
  var burnindex = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red));
  
  var saipan = burnindex
    .rename('NBR')
    .clip(boundary);

  return image.addBands(saipan);
  
};

var finalimage = fullfunction(image).select('NBR');

Map.addLayer(finalimage);
//this works

var new_collection = l8.map(fullfunction);

print(new_collection);
//this now does
```

After running it in GEE code editor, I got result of following image. Displayed image is the first filtered between these two dates: '2019-05-01', '2019-05-30', sorted by 'CLOUD_COVER' and clipped by boundary area. It can also be observed that new mapped collection has an additional band: 'NBR' (visualized inside red rectangle).

[image]